# hide a part of the url (client side)

Tags: javascript, php, url, url-rewriting, hide

How can I hide part of the URL address, only on the client side?

For example, if a visitor clicks on a link on my site that redirects to the domain `www.sitoexample.com/?exemple=4323456`, I want to hide `?exemple=43234566` part of the URL which is nothing more than an id, but only on the client side because the system must recognize that the visit has arrived with the ?exemple=4323456.

So to sum up, the querystring part of the url would only be hidden from the visitor. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Comment: maybe use post instead of get

Comment: You can set a cookie with the parameters and read the cookie on the server

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "POST" Method instead of "GET"

POST = URL invisible.

GET  = URL visible.

To get an idea of each, see:

https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ref_httpmethods.asp

and:

[What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)